# Tips for golfing in PARI/GP

Tags: code-golf, tips

[PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) is a free computer algebra system. It is designed for (algebraic) number theory, not golfing, but that's part of the attraction. Unsurprisingly, it fares best at mathematical tasks; its support for string manipulation is primitive. (Having said that, advice for golfing non-mathematical tasks is also welcome.)

As usual, please post one tip per answer.

These tips should be at least *somewhat* specific to PARI/GP; advice which applies to 'most' languages belongs at [Tips for golfing in <all languages>](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/2605). Some general tips which don't need to be included:

1. Compress whitespace. (In GP all whitespace outside of strings is optional.)
2. Use single-character variables. (There are 50 choices, a-z and A-Z except I and O.)
3. Use `<` and `>` rather than `<=` and `>=` when possible.
4. Chain assignments. (`a=b=c` or `a+=b*=c`)

Answer (score 9):

Use operators to replace commands (or longer operators!) when possible.

`length(v)` → `#v` (saves 5-7 bytes)

`matsize(M)[2]` → `#M` (saves 9-11 bytes)

`matsize(M)[1]` → `#M~` (saves 8-10 bytes)

`floor(x)` → `x\1` (saves 3-5 bytes)

`round(x)` → `x\/1` (saves 2-4 bytes)*

`shift(x,n)` → `x>>n` or `x<<n` (saves 2-6 bytes)

`sqr(x)` → `x^2` (saves 1-3 bytes)

`deriv(x)` → `x'` (saves 4-6 bytes)

`mattranspose(M)` → `M~` (saves 11-13 bytes)

`factorial(n)` → `n!` (saves 8-10 bytes)

`&&` → `&` (saves 1 byte; note that this syntax is deprecated)

`||` → `|` (saves 1 byte; only works in older versions)

* Prior to 2.8.1 (2016) the `\/` operator did not work correctly on t_REAL numbers—update if you haven't!

Comment: `x\/1`: is that designed to be a round operator, or just some sort of magic?

Comment: @primo: Yes, it's a round operator. Not very well-known, though, so I thought I'd mention it. Of course round(x/6) to x\/6 is an even bigger win...

Answer (score 6):

- In a string context (e.g. the arguments of `print` or `Str`), commas are unnecessary:

  ```
  i=99
  print(i" bottles of beer on the wall")
  ```

  This is even true if one of the arguments is an assignment. The following is equivalent to the above:

  ```
  print(i=99" bottles of beer on the wall")
  ```
- Unassigned variables evaluate to their name in a string context:

  ```
  for(i=1,2,print(i" bottl"e" of beer on the wall.");e=es)
  ```

  produces:

  ```
  1 bottle of beer on the wall.
  2 bottles of beer on the wall.
  ```
- In a multi-line context `{ ... }`, the closing brace is unnecessary.

  ```
  print({"this is line one
  this is line two")
  ```

---

**Documentation**

In REPL:
`?*` - show all commands.
`?<command>` - show brief documentation for a command.

Online documentation:
http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/

Comment: The refcard is also very helpful: https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.13.0/refcard.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Some replacements:

- `poldegree(f)` -> `#f'`
- `subst(f,x,y)` -> `x=y;eval(f)` if `x` is not used elsewhere
- `subst(f,x,0)` -> `f%x` but its type is `t_POL` instead of `t_INT`
- `polcoeff(s+O(x^(n+1)),n)` -> `Pol(s+O(x^n*x))\x^n` but its type is `t_POL`
- `polcoeff(s+O(x^(n+1)),n)` -> `Vec(s+O(x^n++))[n]` if the constant term of `s` is nonzero
- `Vecrev(v)~` -> `Colrev(v)`
- `Pol(s+O(x^n))` -> `s%x^n` if `s` is a rational function (e.g., `1/(1-x)`) and `n > 0`
- `(1-x^n)/(1-x)` -> `x^n\(x-1)`
- `matrix(n,n,i,j,e)` -> `matrix(n,,i,j,e)`
- `a[2..#a]` / `a[2..-1]` -> `a[^1]`
- `a[1..-2]` -> `a[^#a]`
- `if(cond0,a,if(cond1,b,c))` -> `if(cond0,a,cond1,b,c)`
- `ceil(x)` -> `-x\-1`

Answer (score 5):

Use set-builder notation to replace apply and select.

`apply(x->thing1(x)&&thing2(x),select(condition,v))` → `[thing1(x)&&thing2(x)|x<-v,condition(x)]`

or

`apply(x->thing1(x)&&thing2(x),v)` → `[thing1(x)&&thing2(x)|x<-v]`

but if you're applying a named function, `apply` is better, since the arguments are implicit:

`[functionName(x)|x<-v]` → `apply(functionName,v)`

Answer (score 5):

Use specialized loops.

GP provides (at least) the following loops: `for`, `forcomposite`, `fordiv`, `forell`, `forpart`, `forprime`, `forstep`, `forsubgroup`, `forvec`, `prod`, `prodeuler`, `prodinf`, `sum`, `sumalt`, `sumdiv`, `sumdivmult`, `suminf`, `sumnum`, `sumnummonien`, `sumpos`.

So don't write `s=0;for(i=1,9,s+=f(i));s` when you could write `sum(i=1,9,f(i))`, don't write `for(n=1,20,f(prime(n)))` when you could write `forprime(p=2,71,f(p))`, and certainly don't write `apply(v->print(v),partitions(4));` instead of `forpart(v=4,print(v))`.

`prodeuler` can be useful as a product over the primes, but note that it returns a `t_REAL` rather than a `t_INT`, so rounding at the end may be necessary depending on the task.

`sumdiv` can be a real lifesaver compared to a simple loop over `divisors`.

`forvec` is a replacement for a whole collection of loops. You can replace (ungolfed)

```
{
for(i=0,9,
  for(j=i,99,
    for(k=i,200,
      f(i,j,k)
    )
  )
);
}
```

with

```
forvec(v=[[0,9], [0,99], [0,200]],
  call(f, v)
,
  1 \\ increasing sequences only
)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Know your built-ins

Like other computer algebra systems, PARI/GP also has a lot of built-ins for number theory, linear algebra, polynomials, and other branches of algebra.

The easy way to find a built-in is looking at the reference card.

- [Reference card for 2.15.1 (the newest version)](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.15.1/refcard.pdf)
- [Reference card for 2.13.3 (the version on ATO)](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.13.3/refcard.pdf)
- [Reference card for 2.11.1 (the version on TIO)](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.11.1/refcard.pdf)

Many built-ins have a prefix to indicate the types they work on. For example:

- Built-ins for matrices usually have the prefix `mat`
- Built-ins for polynomials usually have the prefix `pol`
- Built-ins for power series usually have the prefix `ser`

When you are looking for a built-in, you can type the prefix in the REPL, and press <kbd>tab</kbd>. The command-line completion will tell you what functions it has.

To see the help message of a built-in in the REPL, just type `? functionname`. For a more detailed help message, sometimes with examples, type `?? functionname`.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid `return` when possible.

The final value in the function is returned, so don't write `...;return(x)` but just `...;x`.

If you must use `return`, note that the bare for `return` yields the PARI value `gnil`, which is falsy (coerced into a GP `0` or PARI `gen_0` as needed), so you can usually write `return` rather than `return(0)`.

And (almost?) needless to say, but if you have two values to choose from, much better to return `if(condition,x,y)` than `if(condition,return(x));y`.

Answer (score 3):

## Truthy and Falsy

There isn't a Boolean type in PARI/GP. Truthy and falsy are defined as the following:

- Values that equal to `0` are falsy. This includes real number `0.0`, complex number `0.0+0.0*I`, polynomial `0*x`, power series `0+O(x^3)`, modulo object `Mod(0,3)`, and many others.
- Vector and matrices that are empty or only contains falsy values are falsy. This includes nested falsy vectors like `[0, [0, 0, [[]]]]`.
- Everything else is truthy. In particular, lists, maps, strings, and `Vecsmall`s are always truthy even if they are empty or only contains falsy values.

The simplest way to convert `a` to the "default" truthy / falsy value (i.e., `1` / `0`) is `!!a`.

When testing equality with `==`, every falsy value is equal to `0`. If you need to distinguish between different falsy values, use `===`.

### Use `-` to test equality

For `a` and `b` that can subtract, we can do:

- `if(a==b,c,d)` => `if(a-b,d,c)`
- `a==b&&c` => `a-b||c` if we only need the side effect of `c`.
- `a==b||c` => `a-b&&c` if we only need the side effect of `c`.

Be careful when testing vector equality: only vectors that have the same length can subtract.

### Any and All

There isn't built-in `any` or `all` function in PARI/GP.

When checking if a predicate is true for all or any integers in a range, we can just use `sum` or `prod`.

When checking if any item in a vector is truthy, we don't need a function: the vector itself is truthy if and only if any item in it is truthy.

When checking if all item in a vector is truthy, the following has the same length:

```
vecprod(a)
![!i|i<-a]
```

### Initialize with truthy/falsy

When using functions like `for`, `sum`, `prod`, we usually initialize some variable to `0` and `1`. If the previous expression returns the opposite truthy/falsy value, we can just use it. For example:

```
a=some_truthy_value;for(i=0,n,do_something())
=>
for(i=!a=some_truthy_value,n,do_something())
```

Answer (score 1):

## String replace

PARI/GP doesn't have a string replace built-in, but when you want to replace every occurrence of `a` in `s` by `b`, you can do `strjoin(strsplit(s,a),b)`.

`strjoin` and `strsplit` are introduced in PARI/GP 2.13.0, so they are not supported on TIO.

Answer (score 1):

## Default parameters

In PARI/GP, function parameters default to `0`. This can be useful when you need to initialize a variable to `0`.

For example, instead of `f(x)=i=0;...`, you can write `f(x,i)=...`.

Comment: Along those lines, if you don't return anything, `gnil` is returned automatically, and it functions like `0` in most contexts.